# How do i change properties in other classes in swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, properties, iboutlet

I started programming in swift 3 days ago so this is probably a pretty obvious question, but I couldn't find the answer anywhere else. I am making a version of flappy bird and I'm using a UILabel to display the text, "Touch To Begin" in my GameViewController.swift properties.

```
@IBOutlet weak var touchToBegin: UILabel!
```

In my GameScene.swift class, in the touchToBegin function, I want to change the label text to an empty string so that there isn't text on the screen while the game is being played.

```
GameViewController.touchToBegin.text = ""
```

It gives me an error that says: 'GameViewController.Type' does not have a member named 'touchToBegin'

Do I need to make the variable public or is there a specific way I'm supposed to call it? If not, are there any other options? It seems like it should be pretty simple. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
<terminated>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try, instead, `touchToBegin.text = ""` or `self.touchToBegin.text = ""` or `touchToBegin.hidden = true` ...... if I were you I'd checkout the The Swift Programming Language iBook.  There's a lot of great info in there.

Comment: Thx for the feedback!